# Integration OpenERP with Asterisk

Tags: python, asterisk, odoo

I'm trying to integrate OpenERP and Asterisk with asterisk_click2dial module. Calling from softphone to softphone works, but i cant call from OpenERP to softphone.

manager.conf:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0

[openerp]
secret = openerp
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
read = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user
write = system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user
```

[asterisk server config (img)](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/100/asteriskconf.png/)

I'm sure, user settings are ok.

It doesn't works when *AMI login* is phone number, like in softphone config.

python debugg:

```
[2012-04-17 14:17:44,072][asterisk] INFO:asterisk_click2dial:Asterisk Click2Dial from 103 to 101
[2012-04-17 14:17:44,078][asterisk] WARNING:web-services:The method action_dial_phone of the object crm.lead can not return `None` !
```

asterisk server debugg:

```
== connect attempt from '192.168.1.106' unable to authenticate
```

While catching SIP packages by Wireshark i saw only reciver number (101@192.168.1.100). I didn't see openerp user number (103), but only Unknown@192.168.1.106. But i first time used Wireshark, so maybe it doesn't matter.

Question is: why OpenERP can't call to softphone, but softphone to softphone can?

Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to concentrate on the authentication side.  If OpenERP (which I am not familiar with) can only send a phone number (or extension number) as a username, then you need to set that as your username in manager.conf.  The username portion is what's between the [ and ] above (in this case it's [openerp].  If you do not have the flexibility to set an actual username on the client side of OpenERP, then you'll need to simply replace the [openerp] with [phone_no or ext_no].

Then it should authenticate fine.  Wireshark isn't likely to be terribly helpful in this instance.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed login in manager.conf to 103, now it is the same, as extension number. Asterisk debugg tels me "manager '103' logged on from [ip]", then immediately logs off. I think problem is in python code.

Comment: If I could see it, I could fix it.  If you're still stumped, PM me.

Comment: I think issue is in the _dialplan context_ in openerp config. dialplan [general or from-internal](http://share.qwerty.yum.pl/general.png), dialplan [from-pstn](http://share.qwerty.yum.pl/from-pstn.png) I'll keep trying changing dialplans :)

Comment: Ok, problem solved. dialplan context: from internal, and... I need to have phone connected to asterix! [Ba dum tss](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=583zhKnsDjI)